# Android ошибка: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть проект, раньше всё работало нормально, сейчас при сборке проекта получаю вот такие ошибки

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

И в самой вкладке Manifest merger

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:2 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 1 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

В самом файле манифеста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.***************"
    tools:replace="allowBackup, android:appComponentFactory"
    android:allowBackup="false">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Ну и зависимости

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
}
```

Конечно можно проапдейтить проект на AndroidX, но может быть есть какое-то решение без этого, так как тогда придется прям много всего переписать заново.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Попробуйте вот это добавить в тег аппликэйшн: `android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"`. Возможно, правда, это будет иметь неприятные [последствия](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285362/3212712). Ещё вариант - понизить версию либы с рекламой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже вы не понимаете как работает manifest-merger (объединитель манифеста)

1. У вас в проекте есть 2 или больше манифестов (от подчиненных либ/приложений)
2. В манифестах могут быть противоречащие друг другу элементы (ну например, классика жанра стили/темы)
3. Во время *merge* возникает коллизия, какой элемент взять?
4. Вот здесь то на сцену и выходит `tools:<element>` - по сути инструкция как разрешить коллизию

В вашем конкретном случае у вас есть инструкция `tools:replace="allowBackup, android:appComponentFactory"`, что означает в переводе на русский, взять значения тегов `allowBackup` и `android:appComponentFactory` из текущего манифеста (в котором  задекларирован `tools:replace`).

Далее начинается история с тем, что атрибута `android:appComponentFactory` в текущем манифесте нет... - дальше ошибка, эксепшн, лог и все такое.

2 варианта как решить:

1. Вообще убрать `android:appComponentFactory` из `tools:replace`
2. Вставить значение `android:appComponentFactory` такое же как и в подчиненном манифесте, который спокойно лежит в либе.

Comment: Да, вы правы, из-за не понимания некоторых моментов был лишним tools:replace="allowBackup, , но по итогу проблему решил тем, что таким мигрировал проект на AndroidX, так как по другому просто уже сложно развивать проект.